# Learning Python the Hard Way: Ex16 Extra Credit

Tags: python

I'm stumped when it comes to the 3rd question on the extra credit.  The code in question is this:

```
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
```

The question asks you to "use strings, formats, and escapes to print out line1, line2, and line3 with just one target.write() command instead of 6.

So, I thought I'd write it like this:

```
target.write("%s + \n + %s + \n + %s + \n") % (line1, line2, line3)
```

And it returned:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'tuple.'  I did some research on them and couldn't really find anything, but it returned the same error using %r.

Thinking the + signs were incorrect since it was all a single string, I deleted them for:

```
target.write("%s \n %s \n %s \n") % (line1, line2, line3)
```

Still nothing.  Then I tried:

```
target.write("%s" + "\n" + "%s" + "\n" + "%s" + "\n") % (line1, line2, line3)
```

This one at least changed the error to: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str'.  The same error was produced for this variation:

```
target.write("%s") % (line1 + line2 + line3)
```

Anyway, it's pretty obvious I'm stuck somewhere.  I'm thinking my problem is centered around the %s/%r I'm using, but I can't find an alternative that I think would work, or maybe I'm just writing the write statement incorrectly.

Sorry if this drug on, I just thought I'd try to explain my thought process.  Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Please link to the problem statement

Comment: http://blamcast.net/python/ex16.html

Should all be contained here if you need any other information regarding the problem.

Answer (score 17):

How about this?

```
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

Comment: Huh... so I just didn't nest it correctly in parenthesis?  I see how it makes sense, I guess I was referring too much to the older examples where print statements weren't nested in an operator which had it's own () requirements.

Comment: Yes, the % operator applies to strings. You were trying to apply it to the result of target.write. You could also do `out = "%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3); target.write(out)`

Comment: Yeah, I found a way to make it work earlier by creating a new variable that combined the line1/2/3 variables and printed it that way, but I felt that wasn't exactly what the question was looking for.  Granted, it wasn't as elegant looking as yours, but it got the job done.  Just to clarify one more time:  within the () of the write method, it refers properly to the variables listed, but outside the method it was referring to the result of the method?

Comment: yes, if you do it outside its like `out = target.write(…); out % (line1, line2, line3)`. So the call `target.write(…)` is seen as one expression. This is actually defined by operator precedence, i.e. `(…)` has higher precedence than `%`. So python first calls, `target.write` and then does the formating. Similar to 3 * 4 + 5. First multiply, then add.

Answer (score 1):

The % interpolation operator applies to strings. You're applying it to the return value of target.write, which doesn't return anything (hence NoneType). You want to do the interpolation on the string itself:

```
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3) )
```

Most people learning Python first encounter % in the context of the print statement, so it's understandable to think it's closely connected with output, but it does all its work at the string level.

Comment: -1 The resultant arg of write() will be `"alpha + \n + beta + \n + gamma + \n"`

Comment: Ahh, that's starting to make some sense.  I was wondering why the text file was showing %r or %s (or whatever combination I tried) without actually including the input.

So without being included in the parentheses of the .write() method, the % was referring to something that didn't exist rather than the variables listed after, correct?

Comment: John - Ugh, sorry, didn't look closely at it. Fixing.

Comment: @Dan: more or less correct. If future, if you have a problem with a complicated expression like that, break it up into multiple statements and check each component e.g. `lines_to_write = "%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (yadda, foo, blah)` then `yourfile.write(lines_to_write)`. When you have got it working, DON'T waste time glueing it back again.

Comment: Dan - the % in your original was referring to two things that totally do exist: on the left, the return value of `target.write()`, and on the right, the tuple `(line1,line2,line3)`. `target.write()` returns None, so that's like saying `None % (line1,line2,line3)`, which is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Your original attempts were attempting to use the `%` operator with the return value of `target.write()` -- which is None.  You need to have `%` happen inside the `()` for `target.write`:

```
target.write ( "%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

Note that another solution is:

```
target.write('\n'.join([line1, line2, line3, '']))
```

**Edit**

Added empty string at end to force a third newline (otherwise there would be only two).

Comment: Interesting.  I appreciate the alternative solution.  I haven't come across anything like that yet, but it adds a little extra perspective to see it written another way.

Comment: @Ethan: (1) hello (2) 2nd "solution" omits trailing newline

Comment: @John: (1) howdy! (2) drat. Had it been `print` the newline would be there already, but yeah, no automatic newlines with `.write` -- good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Another method which worked for me in Python 3 is:

```
target.write(f"{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}\n")
```

Answer (score -2):

I myself used this script to write lines in the file for the same question.
 (using python 3.6)

```
target.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3 + "\n")
```

Comment: This doesn't use any string formatting, it's just an inefficient repeated concatenation (it builds five total strings, and four of them are temporaries that get copied to the next string and thrown away). The whole point of the format strings (whether it's `'%s\n%s\n%s\n' % (line1, line2, line3)`, `'{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(line1, line2, line3)` or `f'{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}\n'` is that it builds the result up directly into the final string without repeated concatenation of immutables and the attendant Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm.